# Read a dense matrix from a file directly into a sparse numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a matrix stored in a tab-separated format in a text file. It is stored densely, but I know it is very sparse. I want to load this matrix into one of Python's sparse formats. The matrix is very large, so doing a `scipy.loadtxt(...)` and then converting the resulting dense array to a sparse format would take too much RAM memory in the intermediate step, so that is not an option.

Comment: You'll probably have write your own.  For a start read the csv line by line and collect the sparse inputs - I,j,data of nonzero values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loadtxt` works with an open file, or any iterable that gives it lines.

So one option is to open the file, and perform `loadtxt` on blocks of lines.  Then convert the resulting array to sparse.  Collect those sparse matrices into a list, and use the `block` format to assemble them into one matrix.

I haven't used the `block` format much, but I think it will handle this task correctly.  Under the cover `block` collects the `coo` attributes (`data`, `rows`, `cols`) of each of the blocks, joins them into 3 master `coo` attributes.

Under the cover `loadtxt` just reads each line, parses it into an array or list; collects all those lines into a list, and finally passes that nested list to `np.array()`.

So you could read each line, parse it into a list or array of values, find the nonzero values, and assemble relevant `coo` arrays.

Large sparse matrices are often created by assembling the `data`,`i`, `j` 1d arrays, and then calling `coo_matrix((data,(i,j)),...)`.  One way or other that's what you need to do with this CSV data.

---

Here's a line by line approach, which is equivalent to using `loadtxt` on 1 line chunks:

A test text list, equivalent to a file:

```
In [840]: txt=b"""1,0,0,2,3
0,0,0,0,0
4,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,3,0
""".splitlines()
In [841]: 
In [841]: np.loadtxt(txt,delimiter=',',dtype=int)
Out[841]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0]])
```

Process it line by line

```
In [842]: ll=[]
In [843]: for line in txt:
    ll.append(np.loadtxt([line],delimiter=','))
   .....:     
In [844]: ll
Out[844]: 
[array([ 1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.]),
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.])]
```

Now turn each array into a `coo` matrix:

```
In [845]: lc=[[sparse.coo_matrix(l)] for l in ll]
In [846]: lc
Out[846]: 
[[<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>],
 [<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>],
 [<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>],
 [<1x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]]
```

and assemble the list with `bmat` (a 'cover' for `bsr_matrix`):

```
In [847]: B=sparse.bmat(lc)
In [848]: B
Out[848]: 
<4x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [849]: B.A
Out[849]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.]])
```

`sparse.coo_matrix(l)` is just an easy way of compressing each line to `bmat` compatible objects.

To process the text in 2 line chunks:

```
In [874]: ld=[]
In [875]: for i in range(0,4,2):
    arr = np.loadtxt(txt[i:i+2],delimiter=',')
    ld.append([sparse.coo_matrix(arr)])
   .....:     
In [876]: ld
Out[876]: 
[[<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>],
 [<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]]
```

which feeds `sparse.bmat` just like before.